# How to Validate XML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, validation

How to Validate XML using JavaScript? 
Vin Number must be 17 digits. 
License plate can not have special char. 
Year, Make and Model combination must be validated together and can not be empty.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fleet>
<Vehicle>     
   <Bus>
      <VinNumber>75644444335434516</VinNumber>
      <LicensePlateNumber>4BH241</LicensePlateNumber>
      <Year>1991</Year>
      <Make>Ford</Make>
      <model>Ecoline</model>
 </Bus>
</Vehicle>
</fleet>
```

Comment: Use any xml library for javascript that supports xml schema and write one.

Comment: am halfway there and I have to do using Javascript normal validation.